# Understanding the backward mechanism of LSTMCell in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I want to hook into the backward pass of a LSTMCell function in pytorch so in the initialization pass I do the following (num_layers=4, hidden_size=1000, input_size=1000):

```
self.layers = nn.ModuleList([
        LSTMCell(
            input_size=input_size,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
        )
        for layer in range(num_layers)
    ])

for l in self.layers:
    l.register_backward_hook(backward_hook)
```

In the forward pass I simply iterate the LSTMCell over sequence length and the num_layers as follow:

```
for j in range(seqlen):            
    input = #some tensor of size (batch_size, input_size)
    for i, rnn in enumerate(self.layers):
        # recurrent cell
        hidden, cell = rnn(input, (prev_hiddens[i], prev_cells[i]))
```

Where input is of size `(batch_size, input_size)`, `prev_hiddens[i]` is size of `(batch_size, hidden_size)`, `prev_cells[i]` is of size `(batch_size, hidden_size)`.

In the `backward_hook` I print the size of the tensors that are input to this function:

```
def backward_hook(module, grad_input, grad_output):
    for grad in grad_output:
        print ("grad_output {}".format(grad))

    for grad in grad_input:
         print ("grad_input.size () {}".format(grad.size()))
```

As the results, for the first time `backward_hook` is called for example:

[A] For `grad_output` I get 2 tensors among which the second tensor is `None`. This is understandable because in the backward phase we have a gradient of internal states (c) and gradient of output (h). The last iteration in time dimension has no future hidden so its gradient is None.

[B] For grad_input I get 5 tensors (batch_size=9):

```
grad_input.size () torch.Size([9, 4000])
grad_input.size () torch.Size([9, 4000])
grad_input.size () torch.Size([9, 1000])
grad_input.size () torch.Size([4000])
grad_input.size () torch.Size([4000])
```

My questions are:

(1) Is my understanding from [A] correct?

(2) How do I interpret the 5 tensors from the grad_input tuple? I thought there should have only 3 since there are only 3 inputs to the LSTMCell forward()?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `grad_input` and `grad_output` is wrong. I am trying to explain it with a simpler example.

```
def backward_hook(module, grad_input, grad_output):
    for grad in grad_output:
        print ("grad_output.size {}".format(grad.size()))

    for grad in grad_input:
        if grad is None:
            print('None')
        else:
            print ("grad_input.size: {}".format(grad.size()))
    print()

model = nn.Linear(10, 20)
model.register_backward_hook(backward_hook)

input = torch.randn(8, 3, 10)
Y = torch.randn(8, 3, 20)

Y_pred = []
for i in range(input.size(1)):
    out = model(input[:, i])
    Y_pred.append(out)

loss = torch.norm(Y - torch.stack(Y_pred, dim=1), 2)
loss.backward()
```

The output is:

```
grad_output.size torch.Size([8, 20])
grad_input.size: torch.Size([8, 20])
None
grad_input.size: torch.Size([10, 20])

grad_output.size torch.Size([8, 20])
grad_input.size: torch.Size([8, 20])
None
grad_input.size: torch.Size([10, 20])

grad_output.size torch.Size([8, 20])
grad_input.size: torch.Size([8, 20])
None
grad_input.size: torch.Size([10, 20])
```

> Explanation

- `grad_output`: Gradient of the loss w.r.t. the layer output, `Y_pred`.
- `grad_input`: Gradients of the loss w.r.t the layer inputs. For `Linear` layer, the inputs are the `input` tensor and the `weight` and the `bias`.

So, in the output you see:

```
grad_input.size: torch.Size([8, 20])  # for the `bias`
None                                  # for the `input`
grad_input.size: torch.Size([10, 20]) # for the `weight`
```

---

The `Linear` layer in PyTorch uses a `LinearFunction` which is as follows.

```
class LinearFunction(Function):

    # Note that both forward and backward are @staticmethods
    @staticmethod
    # bias is an optional argument
    def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
        output = input.mm(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)
        return output

    # This function has only a single output, so it gets only one gradient
    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        # This is a pattern that is very convenient - at the top of backward
        # unpack saved_tensors and initialize all gradients w.r.t. inputs to
        # None. Thanks to the fact that additional trailing Nones are
        # ignored, the return statement is simple even when the function has
        # optional inputs.
        input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None

        # These needs_input_grad checks are optional and there only to
        # improve efficiency. If you want to make your code simpler, you can
        # skip them. Returning gradients for inputs that don't require it is
        # not an error.
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
            grad_input = grad_output.mm(weight)
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
            grad_weight = grad_output.t().mm(input)
        if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum(0).squeeze(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias
```

---

For LSTM, there are four sets of weight parameters.

```
weight_ih_l0
weight_hh_l0
bias_ih_l0
bias_hh_l0
```

So, in your case, the `grad_input` would be a tuple of 5 tensors. And as you mentioned, the `grad_output` is two tensors.

Comment: Why in the Linear case (your example) the gradient for input is None and there are two gradients for bias? (is there a typo?)

Comment: I still can't figure why the tensors in grad_input has the sizes in my output. If the weights are included it should have something like (1000x1000) or (1000x4000). The tensors I obtained have no sizes like that.